# Lumia Imaging GifRenderer Never Returns

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, lumia-imaging-sdk

I'm calling the RenderAsync() function of the GifRenderer class but it never returns.  I get no error, it just never comes back.  I'm starting with some byte arrays containing JPEG images.  I create a collection of BufferImageSource objects for sources.

```
var sources = new List<IImageProvider>();
sources.Add(new BufferImageSource(frame.Data.AsBuffer(), ImageFormat.Jpeg));
```

I've even taken it down to only a single source buffer, but it still doesn't help.  I've tried the RenderAsync() call with and without the ConfigureAwait() and that doesn't matter either.  Any other things I can check?

```
using (var gifRenderer = new GifRenderer(sources))
{
  gifRenderer.Duration = 1000 / App.AppSettings.FramesPerSecond;
  gifRenderer.UseGlobalPalette = true;
  gifRenderer.Size = new Size(320, 240);
  var gifbuf = await gifRenderer.RenderAsync().AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);
  // ... and so on
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out.  It wasn't specifically something with the Lumia library.  It was a deadlock caused by a Dispatch Timer.  I'm really not sure what that mattered since shouldn't be on the UI thread when it's asynchronous, but it works if I stop the Dispatch Timer, run the encode, then start it up again.

Comment: Glad it worked out. May I ask what your image source objects were? E.g. if you pass a WriteableBitmap into a BitmapImageSource, there will be a dispatcher dependency there (the data in the WB can only be accessed from the UI thread). Even more insidiously, sometimes the WinRT class framework sometimes hands you a stream with a hidden dispatcher dependency.

Comment: Glad it worked out. May I ask what your image source objects were? E.g. if you pass a WriteableBitmap into a BitmapImageSource, there will be a dispatcher dependency there (the data in the WB can only be accessed from the UI thread). Even more insidiously, sometimes the WinRT class framework sometimes hands you a stream with

Comment: It was a collection of StreamImageSource objects.  That is pretty insidious if it has a dispatcher dependency!

Comment: Yeah. You can sometimes determine if that's the case by following the call stack. I seem to recall that the streams provided by the file picker could have a UI thread dependency.

Comment: To clarify slightly, StreamImageSource has no dependency and goes to some length to avoid them.

Comment: thanks @CÅdahl.  These are not chosen from the picker.  Who knows what it was.  I would have preferred to track it down, but it didn't require me to remove anything important so I was satisfied with just getting it to work!